# Add environment settings to script?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, environment-variable

I am using arc 10.4.1, I am having trouble adding the environment settings into my script.  I want the user to set the environment, without having to hit this button and setting it:

[image]

I have attempted:

```
env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
```

It runs fine, but exports to the folder outside the one I set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my script, sets the Environment Workspace based on a folder/geodatabase, and then copies a pre-existing feature class to that workspace (based on the fact that I don't set a location for the output, just a feature class name).

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.env.workspace)

# Copy existing feature class to location specified above
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(r"D:\GIS\SE\GISSE.gdb\testPoint", "abcd")
```

Note: I tend to use `arcpy.GetParameter()` rather than `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()` for my tool parameters as this allows the objects to be referenced rather than receiving just a string.  I only use `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()` if I specifically require/expect a string, or if an object isn't available.  I have tested both in this case, and I get the same result with both.

In your script tool properties, on the Parameters tab, set your Data type to "Workspace" to enable browsing to a folder or geodatabase workspace.

[image]

To test, run the tool and browse to or enter a workspace path and hit OK

[image]

[image]

By browsing to this new location in Catalog window, I can see that the new feature class was created in the workspace specified by user entry in the tool.

[image]